# Insert value in SQL Server table

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

My table name is `installation_status` and it contains columns like

```
installationid (fk) 
remarks (varchar) 
status (varchar)
```

To insert textbox values to remarks & status at the same time to insert the value of `insallationid` from another table named as

```
(installation)column (installatioid(primary key,identity)).
```

I want the required o/p look like this

```
installationid  remarks  status
73              asd       xxx
```

the value 73 is obtained from installation table column

```
installationid(primarykey(identity(1,1))
```

Mmy .net code is

```
 con = New SqlConnection("server=(local)\sqlexpress;Database=service_request; Uid=service_request;Pwd=test123; ")
 con.Open()
 Try
        Dim s2 As String
        s2 = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value.ToString
        cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into installation_status1 (status1,remarks)values('" + s2 + "','" + txtrmks.Text + "')", con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd1 = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO installation_status1 (installation_id)select installation_id FROM installation1", con)
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Lblmsg.Text = "error in recording the information: " + ex.Message
    End Try
    con.Close()
```

Obtained o/p liked this

```
 null    asd    xx
 78      null   null
```

pls help to me get the required o/p

Comment: what you need is pivot query. look it up on BooksOnline

Comment: It seems like you are having a bit of trouble with understanding SQL It's a set-based language; it's not proceedural like VB, C#, and many other languages are. You need to keep in mind that at some point your installation1 table will have many records, so when your user wants to insert a new installation_status1 record for a particular installation, how does your application know which installation the user is talking about? This is the main question that you need to answer in order to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems mainly from the fact that you are performing 2 separate INSERT statements where you should be performing only 1.

The second INSERT statement is completely wrong:

```
INSERT INTO installation_status1 (installation_id)select installation_id FROM installation1
```

This statement will insert new records with null values for the `remarks` column and the `status` column; when you execute this statement, then for every record in the installation1 table at that time you will be inserting a new corresponding record into the installation_status1 table.  I'm sure that this is not at all what you want.

Your first INSERT statement should look something like this:

```
insert into installation_status1 (installation_id,status1,remarks)values(" + installationId + ",'" + s2 + "','" + txtrmks.Text + "')
```

(Side Note:  You are potentially opening yourself up to "SQL Injection" with this approach, because it looks like you are directly inserting user input into your query.  Consider using [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead.)

I've added the `installation_id` column to the insert statement, and I've also specified the value for that column using a (currently undefined) variable named `installationId`.  You will need to figure out how to populate the installationId variable; your application needs to know ahead of time to which "installation" the user is trying to apply remarks and status, meaning that before you reach this point your application should already know what the correct `installationId` is.